# onChat() not being called

Tags: java, bukkit

This code should wait for `.help` to be typed in chat, then send a message saying `"Help text."`.
Nothing happens.

```
package testplugin.HelpMe;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin;
import org.bukkit.command.Command;
import org.bukkit.command.CommandSender;
import org.bukkit.event.player.PlayerChatEvent;

public class HelpMe extends JavaPlugin implements {

    Logger log;

    public void onEnable(){
        log = this.getLogger();
        log.info("Your plugin has been enabled!");
    }

    public void onDisable(){
        log.info("Your plugin has been disabled.");
    }

    public boolean onCommand(CommandSender sender, Command command, String label, String[] args) {
        return false;


      }
      public void onChat(PlayerChatEvent event) {
            if (event.getMessage().startsWith(".help"))
            {
              event.getPlayer().sendMessage("Help text.");
              event.setCancelled(true);
            }
      }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

I think you want the `@EventHandler` annotation:

```
@EventHandler public void onChat(PlayerChatEvent event) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You are missing 3 things:

- `implements Listener` (you missed that in the code you provided, copy paste error?)
- The `@EventHandler` annotation on the `onChat` method
- The code which actually registers your plugin to listen for events, which is `getServer().getPluginManager().registerEvents(this, this);` in your `onEnable`

So, the end result would look like:

```
package testplugin.HelpMe;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin;
import org.bukkit.command.Command;
import org.bukkit.command.CommandSender;
import org.bukkit.event.player.PlayerChatEvent;
import org.bukkit.event.Listener;
import org.bukkit.event.EventHandler;

public class HelpMe extends JavaPlugin implements Listener {

    Logger log;

    public void onEnable(){
        log = this.getLogger();
        log.info("Your plugin has been enabled!");
        //Tell the server that this plugin provides an event listener (which is this class), and to invoke event handlers in that class
        getServer().getPluginManager().registerEvents(this, this);
    }

    public void onDisable(){
        log.info("Your plugin has been disabled.");
    }

    public boolean onCommand(CommandSender sender, Command command, String label, String[] args) {
        return false;
    }

    //Marks that this method handles the PlayerChatEvent
    @EventHandler
    public void onChat(PlayerChatEvent event) {
        if (event.getMessage().startsWith(".help"))
        {
          event.getPlayer().sendMessage("Help text.");
          event.setCancelled(true);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

All I needed to add was this to my code and it worked perfectly!

```
public void onEnable() {
    getServer().getPluginManager().registerEvents(this, this);
}
```

And `@EventHandler` in front of `onChat()`.

The finished code:

```
package testplugin.HelpMe;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin;
import org.bukkit.command.Command;
import org.bukkit.command.CommandSender;
import org.bukkit.event.player.PlayerChatEvent;

public class HelpMe extends JavaPlugin implements {

Logger log;

public void onEnable(){
    log = this.getLogger();
    log.info("Your plugin has been enabled!");
    getServer().getPluginManager().registerEvents(this, this);
}

public void onDisable(){
    log.info("Your plugin has been disabled.");
}

public boolean onCommand(CommandSender sender, Command command, String label, String[] args) {
    return false;


  }
  @EventHandler public void onChat(PlayerChatEvent event) {
        if (event.getMessage().startsWith(".help"))
        {
          event.getPlayer().sendMessage("Help text.");
          event.setCancelled(true);
        }
  }
}
```